# How can I create an installation package?

Tags: packaging, qt

I'm programming a Qt app in Ubuntu. Well, I'm newbie in Linux but good at Qt. I wanna know how to Create Qt Static Libraries(Qt has installed from Synaptic), Create an installation package and How to put the app on the Applications Menu. Please Put some links for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the overly broad question and "please put some links for me" gives the impression you have done zero effort so far to find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
I've found a link, but I can't describe all the process for you here; the reason is explained in first few lines of where I've found a little tutorial:

> This article wants to be an introduction to creating .deb packages, meaning I will not get into more advanced procedures like creating a menu entry, custom configuration, explaining the rules file and so on because this how-to would have ~20 pages or so.

check out [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html) for a small article about this. also it has several links for a detailed & complete discussion, like [this article that seems to be the official one.](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-start.en.html)
Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html)